# Heartbeat on SLES 11

Tags: sles, heartbeat, linux-ha

I am trying to setup Linux-HA (Heartbeat) on a new SLES 11 Server anyone know of a good step-by-step for this the site's docs leave a little to be desired...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on the same challenge, and here are two links that have helped:

Novell's documentation on HA, which is what you are already probably looking at:

http://novell.com/documentation/sle_ha/book_sleha/?page=/documentation/sle_ha/book_sleha/data/book_sleha.html

Load balancing howto from Novell communities:

http://www.novell.com/communities/node/4846/load-balancing-howto-lvs-ldirectord-heartbeat-2

Download the SLES 11 High Availability Extension as an add-on from the Novell site. It was not grouped under Suse Enterprise Linux as I had expected, but was in its own category for download. Once HAE is added as a source, you can select Software Management, Patterns, and choose High Availability to install all packages at once.

Still working on the configuration part, though.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

1. Dowload the latest Heartbeat 2.99 source-code that you are able to obtain
2. `./configure help` - configure it with the settings that you need
3. `make srpm`
4. Go to the srpm and do a `rpmbuild --rebuild` to it.

If you need DRBD, too - same thing.

That way you can use the old Heartbeat-Cluster-Stack (and DRBD8) without the need to buy a HAE licence.